# TreeBagger (Random Forests) Parameters in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, opencv, machine-learning, random-forest, supervised-learning

When I compared the Random Forest implementation of MATLAB (`TreeBagger` class) with the OpenCV implementation (Random Trees class), I found that several parameters that are present in the latter were not present in the former.

The parameters of interest are the maximum depth of the trees (max_depth), and max_categories.

Does anyone know how to access these parameters in MATLAB?

Answer (score 1):

These parameters are not available in the MATLAB implementation of bagged decision trees, `TreeBagger`.

Comment: Thank you Sam for your answer, but i already know that the TreeBagger class does not provide any kind of information about the two parameters mentioned above (That's why i have posted this question). I want to know how is this sheduled in Matlab, since these parameters are of great importance when runing the Algorithm.

Comment: What do you mean by "how is this scheduled"? Are you asking when (if) MathWorks plan to implement these parameters? I'm not aware of any plans to implement them, and if MathWorks did intend to I don't think they would publish that intention in advance. Bear in mind that `TreeBagger` is not Random Forests, it's an implementation of bagged decision trees that can be made to behave in a way that is mostly similar to Random Forests. There's no reason it has to have exactly the same parameters as another implementation.

Comment: Anyway, the parameter that particularly interests me is the maximum depth of the trees. It influences their ability to overfit or no. Is this parameter fixed or it changes from one iteration to another? i find strange that MATHWORKS did not bring a way to handle it.

Comment: It doesn't seem that strange to me - there are better ways to control the complexity of a tree than by simply cutting it at a specific depth (such as pruning, or restricting the number of observations per leaf node). In any case, whether you find it strange or not, the answer to your original question is that the parameters are not available in `TreeBagger`, even if they are in OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

The command `B.Trees{1}.NumNodes` will return you the number of nodes of the first tree, where `B` is your model.

And according to [this paper](http://www.dtc.umn.edu/~odlyzko/doc/arch/extreme.heights.pdf) the average hight of a binary tree is calculated:

Hight = sqrt(2*pi*n), with n being the number of nodes.

See page 2, which is quite close to the bottom of the .pdf because it's reversed.

However, I have my doubt about this formula...